# ¿como configurar las variables de entorno en Express.js?

Tags: nodejs, express

quiero configurar las variables de entorno, por ejemplo para poner la aplicacion en produccion o en development.

Primero no se cual es la mejora manera, si con un archivo .env, o por comandos.

por comandos he probado

```
export NODE_ENV = production
export NODE_ENV = "production"
set NODE_ENV = "production"
set NODE_ENV = production
```

nada.

Con ficheros he probado a poner un .env con esto mismo. e instalar

node-env-file
dotenv-safe tambien probé

y nada.

Luego intente en el index.js y en el app.js añadir esto

```
var env = require('node-env-file'); // .env file
env(__dirname + '/.env');
```

y tampoco, esta vez me daba errores al intentar arrancarlo..

¿como se hace?

gracias.

edito. es en windows

Answer (score 2):

En varios proyectos en los que trabajo con node empleamos .dotenv-safe de este modo

```
require('dotenv-safe').config({ allowEmptyValues: true });
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

exports.server = app.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
    LOG.info('Servidor levantado en el puerto ' + process.env.PORT);
});
```

Muy importante que tengas tanto el fichero .env como el .env.example para la validación de las variables de entorno. El .env nunca se añade al repo y tienes que añadirlo en el .gitignore para que no se suba nunca. Por motivos de seguridad no querrás tener tus cadenas de conexión y demás datos sensibes en el repo.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Así quedaría el .env.example

```
PORT=
```

Y así tu .env

```
PORT=2500
```

Al arrancar la aplicación debes correr con `npm start`, o si tienes creado algún comando en el campo scripts de tu package.json correr ese comando.

Te muestro un ejemplo de los comandos que tengo en el proyecto:

```
"start_dev": "nodemon --inspect ./app.js",
"start_dev_inspect": "nodemon --inspect ./app.js",
```

Abres la consola en la carpeta donde tienes el proyecto y ejecutas `npm run start_dev`

Recuerda haber ejecutado un `npm i` previa ejecución y tener instalado node en tu sistema operativo.